# Show animation after user switches to the tab

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-animations

If a user opens page in new a tab in the background, Css animations are played before he/she switches to the page. Is there any way to show css-animation after user selects the tab ?

Comment: Yes, When user switches to your tab.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using Page Visibility API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/
might not be supported in older browsers, though

Comment: simple example would be appreciated though.

Comment: It is neded for newer browser because css animations doesn't work either.

Comment: There's a simple example on how to use the changeVisibility event in The VisibilityChange Event section of the article

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this isn't possible with pure CSS, since CSS is just in charge of displaying the webpage. I think it could be possible with Javascript using `onblur` and `onfocus` events. Take a look at http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus which has the information and a demo (that does work in Chrome).

Your milage may vary since I could see some security issues with knowing if a user is actively viewing a page or not. I haven't tested this in all browsers

Comment: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/ - the demo is a great jsFiddle in this case. Just visit the page, and then click on the text box, then your address bar.